# Learning SQL in Free Time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

[image]
So i have the following table

```
 EMPNO ENAME                DEPTN JOB                  HIREDDATE     SALARY
```

---

```
   111 Narayan              R22   Electrical           26-DEC-99       5000
   108 Horen                P69   PWD                  10-DEC-95      10000
   130 Roy                  A13   Security             15-SEP-01      25000
   420 Roy                  D12   IT                   15-SEP-99       2500
   100 Allu                 A13   Security             26-JAN-15      15000
```

With datatypes

`EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(38),
 ENAME                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20),
 DEPTNO                                             VARCHAR2(5),
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(20),
 HIREDDATE                                          DATE,
 SALARY                                             NUMBER(38)`

I want to try to create a stored procedure 
   a) Changing the hire date of any employee.
   b) Performing DML commands (Insert, Update and Delete)
   c) Multiplying two numbers

I tried to use this code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ChangeHired @EmpNo int, @Hired date
AS
ALTER TABLE Employee01 MODIFY HireDate = @Hired WHERE EmpNo = @EmpNo
GO;
```

But it doesn't work in Oracle 10g. Need some help.

Edit: UPDATE Employee01 SET HireDate = @Hired WHERE EmpNo = @EmpNo should be used that was a mistake from my side but still the code is not executed.

Comment: Hope you are using DLL statement instead of DML

Comment: You have said that `the code is not executed.`, how do you know it is not executed? How are you actually executing it? Are you getting any errors when you call the procedure? In your screenshot you don't have any code that executes the procedure, all you do is create it. Is that the issue?

Comment: Yes. But to execute i need to use 'code'EXEC ChangeHired EmpNo = '111', Hired = '26-Jan-01';'code' but i can't seem to use it

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
update Employee01 set HireDate = @Hired WHERE EmpNo = @EmpNo
```

You have just created the procedure, to make it work you have to call it, Call the procedure using,

```
execute procedure_name(parameter1, parameter2);
```

Alter statement should be used only when modifying your structure of the table. While working with data, please use only DML's.

Comment: I have uploaded a pic. actually i'm not getting error but the code doesn't execute

Comment: You have created the procedure successfully. Call the procedure to test. Hope you are not calling it. Provided the solution to call

Answer (score 0):

Syntax you used (or Jim suggested) isn't Oracle. Should be something like this (including that "multiplying" example you asked for):

Sample data (only minimum columns needed for the procedure to work):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From employee1;

     EMPNO HIREDDATE
---------- ----------
       111 08.06.2020
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure changehired(par_empno in int, par_hired in date)
  2  is
  3    a number := 2;
  4    b number := 3;
  5    result number;
  6  begin
  7    update employee1 set
  8      hireddate = par_hired
  9      where empno = par_empno;
 10
 11    result := a * b;
 12    dbms_output.put_line(a || ' * '|| b || ' = ' || result);
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing: once the procedure is **created**, you have to **execute** it. In order to see result of `dbms_output.put_line`, enable serveroutput in tool you use (for SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, execute `set serveroutput on`).

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2    changehired(111, date '2020-06-08');
  3  end;
  4  /
2 * 3 = 6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from employee1;

     EMPNO HIREDDATE
---------- ----------
       111 08.06.2020

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm getting the error Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Comment: Might be because of misspelled "hireDdate"; fixed. If that's not it, run `show err` to display which error you got.

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: ; is with authid as cluster order using external deterministic parallel_enable pipelined

Comment: I modified the answer and included "real" code which actually compiles and *does something*. Have a look.

Comment: I Got the Multiplication running in separate code but i am still getting an error in the update one

Comment: Maybe you do, but - I can't debug mode I can't see.